# Incorrect Exit Code returned by Process.ExitCode Property

Tags: c++, .net, process

I have a native C++ application that I am running as a process during the execution of a C++/CLI application and I am seeing some strange behaviour with the exit code. I expect the exit code to be 0 when the process exits correctly but Process.ExitCode returns -529697949. However, when I debug the C++ application I can see that the exit code being returned is actually 0. Why would the Process.ExitCode property not match this value?

Answer (score 9):

The absolute most important assumption to make when a program misbehaves is to **never** assume it is a bug in code that's used by hundreds of thousands of programmers and runs on half a billion machines.  Assume it is a problem in your program first.

Armed with that knowledge, take a better look at the number.  A good strategy when the number looks large and random is always to convert it hex.  -529697949 = 0xe06d7363.  Shazam, magic number, googles well too.  That's the value of a Windows exception code.  e0 makes it a fatal error, 6d7363 are ASCII codes that spell "msc".

Your program crashed on an unhandled C++ exception.

Comment: +1: this is one of those classical "if I could only up vote twice answers": once for the first paragraph and twice for the note about hex error codes (well actually trice for even solving the root cause)